# Jquery add HTML from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jQuery to add a number to the end of a navigation menu list item. This is the number of products on another page. Currently a single list item looks something like this:

```
<li class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" role="tablist">
<a title="New In" href="http://example.com/shop/clothing/new-in">New In</a>
</li>
```

However I want to add the number of items directly after 'New' for example 'New (20)'. This number is located on items href, in the following place on that page:

```
<div class="paging">
<span class="itemcount">174</span>
</div>
```

Each list item has a different href but the same class which contains the unique number that I need. Any ideas?

I have tried:

```
$("#ui-id-12 > .ui-accordion > li:eq(0) > a:eq(0)").replaceWith('<a title="New In" href="http://example.com/shop/clothing/new-in">New In ' + $(this).load("http://m.example.com/shop/clothing/new-in.html .itemcount") + '</a>');
```

Comment: are you not using a database for your items? if not, then how are you populating them? if you're using a server side script, I dont see the issue. If you're using javascript to pull from a CSV file or something, I still dont see the issue.

Comment: [OBJECT OBJECT] is being printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way for you to get the value you are looking for:

```
$(this).load("http://m.example.com/shop/clothing/new-in.html", function(data){
  alert(data.match(/<span class="itemcount">(\d+)<\/span>/)[1]);
  $("#span-id").text(data.match(/<span class="itemcount">(\d+)<\/span>/)[1]);
  // for putting stuff into a <span> :)
});
```

---

You might want to make a <span> with a specific ID to put the loaded content into like so:

```
<a title="New In" href="http://example.com/shop/clothing/new-in">New In <span id="span-id"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

look up .append()
Which appends craps within any html tags with an closing tag

```
$('a').append("123");
```